# Pycharm on Ubuntu18.04 - Hidden folders from previous versions in home directory

Tags: pycharm, ubuntu-18.04

as the title suggests, I'm currently using Pycharm Professional 2020.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.
In my home folder, I have a bunch of hidden folders from previous versions of Pycharm (.PyCharm2019.1, .PyCharm2019.2, .PyCharm2019.3), which sum up to roughly 3 GB of space.
I seem to understand these should be configuration files for the previous version of the IDE, but in this case I was a little surprised about thir size. I've been using some deep learning libraries, so the folder size could be due to the pre-trained models that are automatically downloaded.

Anyway, considering I don't plan to get back to previous versions of Pycharm, can I delete these folders without any risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 100% delete those folders since they're only mostly important for the preferences and they wont affect your new version (other then maybe forcing you the reset your pycharm manually but that's not a big deal)

As for the size of the folders it probably contains also cache and/or tons of logs from your projects.